# Is there a way to get QXmlStreamReader to cope with malformed XML?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing

I am trying to parse some values from website. To accomplish this I am using `QXmlStreamReader`. After I start parsing I receive XML Error: "Expected '=', but got '>'.". It breaks on this malformed element:

```
<tbody pageStartAt >
```

I suppose that reason of this is because standard stands that everything after main name of the tag should have some values attached to it like this:

```
<tbody pageStartAt="2" > - this is working.
```

My question is - is there any way to prevent this ? I just want to ignore subtags that do not have values. I would rather avoid using QWebKit - I think this is overkill.

Comment: What you're parsing is not XML, thus you can't expect `QXmlStreamReader` to cope with it. It should be a simple matter to patch the reader to accept such malformed XML, though. It'll be less work than any other solution, most likely we're talking about a 2-3 line patch :)

Comment: Most of the time QXmlStreamReader will keep chugging along in after an error.  What exactly do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: It sets QXmlStreamReader into error state, which cannot be removed. (there is clear method - but it also resets offset of characters processed).

Comment: Not really a solution. But if this is the only error and always the same error, the easiest way would probably be to simply preprocess the file and change those lines. Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Already thought about this but I would rather not change this since there are many more places just as this one with different names. If nothing possible I will use QRegExp and parse it myself.

Comment: It's a little bit hacky, but one solution for parsing HTML with an XML parser is to run it through [TidyLib](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert it to XHTML.

Comment: @Bowdzone Wait a minute, are we seriously arguing that a 2-3 line patch to Qt, that you already have sources for and should be compiling yourself anyway, is more work than having to patch up the XML in some other way? Why not leverage the parser that already exists in the reader and make it do your bidding? `QRegExp` cannot parse XML due to fundamental theoretical reasons, so let's not even start about that. You got the source to Qt, **use it**.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm not arguing.  I never looked at the sources of `QXmlReader` so I can't judge how complex such a change would be. I just said that if that _is the only error_ it would maybe be easier. A patch would definitely a better way as I stated that my suggestion is _not really a solution_.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is usage of HTMLTidy (thanks for advice to @MrEricSir) It repairs broken XML. One downgrade is fact that it adds unnecessary tags like /body/ etc.